# problems printing Reverse Array from .dat file JAVA (Yes i have looked, still cannot figure it out)

Tags: java, arrays, reverse

This is my 1st post on this website. So I apologize if do not format this message properly.
For my project we are told to import a .dat file into the program and have the program read the file in reverse and print it on the screen. So far I have been able to print it on the screen however not in reverse. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;               //Imports any file operation (ie Reading or Writing)
import java.util.*;             //Imports classes from util 

public class program2
{
    public static void main(String [] ars) throws IOException
    {
        int [] Values;              //creating array called value
        Values = new int [20];      //establishing array has 20 cells
        int k;                          //creating counter integer

        Scanner InputFile = new Scanner( new FileReader("temp.dat"));       
        /*temp.dat is simply a .dat file containing integers 1-20 in ascending order*/

        for (k = Values.length - 1 ; k >= 0 ; k--)
        {
            Values[k] = InputFile.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Cell " + k + " contains a value of " + Values[k]);
        }

        InputFile.close();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your program you are reading the data from start to end and putting the results in an array in reverse order..the problem is that you are printing while reading.
A solution is to cycle again after the first cycle through Values from 0 to Values.length and print the result

Comment: thank you for the help man. I was just being silly -.- once again thank you for being patient with the noob =P

Answer (score 0):

Your **Values** array has values in the reverse order. But just you are printing it as you want. You are trying to print it from last index. Try to print it outside the loop then it would print it in the fashion you want.

change from

```
  for (k = Values.length - 1 ; k >= 0 ; k--)
    {
        Values[k] = InputFile.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Cell " + k + " contains a value of " + Values[k]);
    }

    InputFile.close();
```

To

```
  for (k = Values.length - 1 ; k >= 0 ; k--)
        {
            Values[k] = InputFile.nextInt();
        }

        for (k =0 ; k <= Values.length - 1 ; k++)
        {
        System.out.println("Cell " + k + " contains a value of " + Values[k]);
        }
        InputFile.close();
```